# How do I get posts by facebook page on it's own wall?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I thought this would be the most trivial thing in facebook api but I can't seem to figure it out. I want to get posts by a facebook page on it's own wall. That's all. `/feed` gives me posts by others mixed with page's posts. `/posts` gives me posts by the page on other peoples' wall mixed with it's own posts on it's own wall. I only want the posts we see on the page's wall, when you choose "Posts by page".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> /posts gives me posts by the page on other peoples' wall mixed with it's own posts on it's own wall.

This is not entirely correct. `/posts` gives the user's own posts, whether that may be in a comment or on a post by a fan on a page's timeline.

*Pages cannot write on a user's timeline*

Facebook also has intentionally added stories such as comments to the `/posts` endpoint so you will have to filter these out after.

Comment: Oh you are right. They were comments and not posts on other users' walls. I decided to filter the posts at the client side.